# A local/internal deployment of something like Campfire for developers

Tags: collaboration, web-browser

I've been looking at [Campfire by 37Signals](http://campfirenow.com/) and it looks like a great tool for collaboration between developers but we need something that can be deployed internally. Any good options out there?

Comment: What specific features would you look for to make it programming related?

Comment: Syntax highlighting would be nice, maybe diffs of files as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Teambox](http://teambox.com/) appears to have similar features. You can test it on the hosted version, then head to the [github project](https://github.com/teambox/teambox) for the source code and installation instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Campfire is a very specialized tool with specific features; I cannot remember seeing any open-source projects that mirrored that functionality, however there may be non-open-source options out there that could be deployed internally.

With WebSockets and Node.js it would be fairly easy to roll your own solution quite rapidly if there was a specific feature-set that you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the info, any good references you'd recommend?

Comment: There's a few approaches to building a real-time chat program. Node.js uses Google's V8 JavaScript engine to provide a foundation for building asynchronous applications, combine this with WebSocket's bidirectional capabilities and you could easily build a quite functional chat application that wouldn't bog down your server. Other popular alternatives for doing real-time chat applications like that include Erlang (steep learning curve but very powerful), Ruby 1.9.2 (with actors, not as steep of a learning curve), and Go (bit steeper than Ruby, but still pretty easy to work with).

Answer (score 0):

The web apps provided by Atlassian can be installed on your own servers and have some  collaboration features in their [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) product.  It also integrates with their bug-tracking/project management system called [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/).